# Swift: Create Custom UISlider with Custom Subview

Tags: swift, uislider

I am trying to make a `UISlider` that isn't subclassed from `UISlider` and have a custom view that indicates the slider's value. I have found that the default Apple view that moves across the slider to be undesirable and I would like to add my own view instead. I have come across no documentation or tutorials out there on how to do this. So does anyone out there have an idea on how I would do this?

*EDIT*

How do I change round thing?

[image]

Comment: The first part of the question does not make much sense. Are you trying to make a custom UIView that behaves like a UISlider?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what we need.

Comment: Take a look at TGPControls, it's highly customizable: https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/TGPControls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UISlider has plenty of methods on it that let you reskin it, including [changing the thumb image](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uislider/1621336-setthumbimage) and [changing the size of the thumb](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uislider/1621344-thumbrect).

You can draw your numbers as a subview or sublayer of the slider, or just put them in a custom view behind the slider.